# How to determine ndk-build to create absolute path C++ dependencies?

Tags: android, c++, makefile, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm using `ndk-build` with **C++** source code to create a shared library for an Android application.

The dependency files that are automatically created under the **`obj/local`**
directory use relative paths.
***Such as***:

```
C:\Workspace\MyProject\Build\NDK\jni\\..\\..\\..\Source\SomeHeaderFile.h
```

I would like to have **absolute** paths in these dependency files, so the above example would be ***generated as***:

```
C:\Workspace\MyProject\Source\SomeHeaderFile.h
```

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: No, this is not supported afaik. Why does it matter what format they're in? Those don't need to be read by humans.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @DanAlbert. It does matter to me. These dependency paths can get very long when there are multiple indirections like that, e.g.
_C:\Project\Build\..\Source\Module0\..\Module1\..\Module2\..\etc_.

In this case it could just be _C:\Project\Source\Module8_, for example. It has come to the point where the paths exceed the Windows path length limit.

Comment: Yeah, your options for solving that are either move your project closer to the root of the drive, reorganize to not have such deep paths, or use an OS that doesn't have such short path length limits. If you want to go the latter route, you could try using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10, or a Linux VM (a Linux VM would outperform both WSL and the native windows build, btw).